# Use bsxfun function to find Max entry of matrix

Tags: matlab

For a given set of `q` and `r`, I want to find the maximum of `Tp=x * log(1 + (q* r (1 - 1/y)* (2/x - y))/(1 + r* (1 - 1/y) + q* (2/x - y)))` for `x` in (0,1) and `y` in (1,2).

I can calculate them using two `for` loops, but when I use really small steps sizes for `x` and `y`, e.g., 0.00001, this takes a long time. But I know that if I get `Tp` as a matrix for all `x` and `y`, i.e., `Tp` is matrix of size `length(x) x length(y)`, it may easier and faster. As I read, `bsxfun(@times,..)` may be helped, but I don't know how I can apply it in my problem.

Here is what I have tried, but it doesn't give correct output. Here I used larger step size for understanding. Can someone fix this issue in my code?

```
function maxTp
hvar=0.1:0.2:1; 
hl=length(hvar);
q=hvar; r=hvar;
stepx=0.2;stepy=0.1; 
y0=1.1; x0=0.1;
x=x0:stepx:1; y=y0:stepy:2;
ox = zeros(hl,1); oy = zeros(hl,1);
MaxTp = zeros(hl,1);
for k=1:hl
    Tp = bsxfun(@times,log(1 + (q(k)*r(k)*(1 - 1./y).*(2./x - y))./(1 + r(k)*(1 - 1./y) + q(k)*(2./x - y))).',x);
    MaxTp(k,1)=max(max(Tp));
    [p, q] = ind2sub(size(Tp),find(Tp==MaxTp(k,1)));
    ox(k,1)=x0+(p-1)*stepx; 
    oy(k,1)=y0+(q-1)*stepy; 
end
```

Comment: Why not use a dedicated optimisation function such as `fmincon`?

Comment: I may use, but this is not the only problem I want to solve by using this technique. That is why I am trying for alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this inside your `for` loop:

```
Tp = bsxfun(@(x,y) log(1+(q(k)*r(k)*(1 - 1./y).*(2./x - y))./(1 + r(k)*(1 - 1./y) + q(k)*(2./x - y)))*x,x,y.'); %\\'
MaxTp(k,1)=max(max(Tp));
[p2, q2] = ind2sub(size(Tp),find(Tp==MaxTp(k,1)));
ox(k,1)=x0+(p2-1)*stepx;
oy(k,1)=y0+(q2-1)*stepy;
```

I changed the `bsxfun` to do the calculation in the function part rather than the vector inputs, and you were also overwriting `p` and `q` as the results of `ind2sub`.

You can also use `fmincon` (be aware the maximisation means we need to minimise the negative of the function). The following code goes inside the `for` loop:

```
f=@(x,y) log(1+(q(k)*r(k)*(1 - 1./y).*(2./x - y))./...
    (1 + r(k)*(1 - 1./y) + q(k)*(2./x - y)))*x;
o(:,k)=fmincon(@(x) -f(x(1),x(2)),[0.5;0.5],[],[],[],[],[0;1],[1;2]);
```

`o(:,k)` gives the `x` and `y` coordinates of the maximum, I think it's different to your `ox` and `oy` variables though.

Comment: Thanks @ David. BTW, how do I use `fmincon` when I have 2 variable to optimize?

Comment: Thanks again @David, I will try to understand this.  If you dont mind pls let me know why do you use `[0.5;0.5]`?

Comment: That's an initial guess to start the minimisation, actually, it should be `[0.5;1.5]`.